# View document library metadata in Outlook

Tags: 2007, document-library, outlook, metadata

I've connected my document library to Outlook and I was wondering if there's any way to view the document's metadata? At the moment the documents only have a Modified By name, document title and date. Is there any way to see the other fields?

Answer (score 1):

1

Open a Web browser and navigate to the SharePoint address provided by the intranet administrator.

2

Click the "Actions" toolbar button and select "Connect to Outlook." Click "Yes" to confirm that you want to connect to the SharePoint library. The software connects to your Outlook and opens Outlook automatically.

3

Look in the left navigation panel. A list of metadata is shown for the SharePoint documents and network resources for your department. SharePoint segments data by company department, so you can only see the information related to your department set up on the intranet.

4

Click a document name to view the content of the file. You can also double-click the file to open it and edit the file's content.

Read more: How to Display Sharepoint Metadata in Outlook | eHow.com http://www.ehow.com/how_12175020_display-sharepoint-metadata-outlook.html#ixzz24vuZx0Jd

appart from that youll need a third party app that can do it for you with the option to see hidden metadata like:

mail2share

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UJwB2XdgTI

or

http://www.macroview.com.au/blog/archive/2011/02/23/capturing-metadata-with-macroview-dmf.aspx

Comment: Could you explain step 3 more? I understand and have completed 1, 2 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint (Library or List) items show a limited Fields and also limited permission. we can't checkput-checkin and Edit, so in this case we have to go with sharePoint Workspace as my knowledge.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean. I don't want to check in/out or edit documents I just want the metadata to be visible